# Uncaught TypeError: grid.imagesLoaded is not a function

Tags: javascript, laravel, webpack

I'm trying to make a structure that I have acquired as a ready-made theme compatible with SEO. I am in a situation like I have exemplified below. When I use **npm run dev** no error in the terminal but developer console response like the image below.

[Developer Console Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ASyA.png)

As you can see Uncaught TypeError: grid.imagesLoaded is not a function. I am using webpack in Laravel and already included imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js

Here is the code:

**webpack.mix.js**

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .postCss('resources/css/app.css', 'public/css', [
        require('postcss-import'),
        require('tailwindcss'),
    ])
    .webpackConfig(require('./webpack.config'));

/* Custom Mix Assets */

mix.styles([
    'public/guest/css/bootstrap-custom.css',
    'public/guest/css/ionicons.min.css',
    'public/guest/css/tiny-slider.css',
    'public/guest/css/lity.min.css',
    'public/guest/css/simplebar.min.css',
    'public/guest/css/jquery.mb.YTPlayer.min.css',
    'public/guest/css/main.css',
    'public/guest/css/colors/main-darkblue.css',
    'public/guest/css/custom.css',
], 'public/css/bundle.css').sourceMaps().version();

mix.js([
    'public/guest/js/jquery.min.js',
    'public/guest/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js',
    'public/guest/js/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js',
    'public/guest/js/isotope.pkgd.min.js',
    'public/guest/js/animatedModal.js',
    'public/guest/js/tiny-slider.js',
    'public/guest/js/lity.min.js',
    'public/guest/js/simplebar.min.js',
    //'public/guest/js/jquery.mb.YTPlayer.min.js',
    'public/guest/js/main.js',
    'public/guest/js/custom.js',
], 'public/js/bundle.js').version();

mix.webpackConfig(webpack => {
    return {
        plugins: [
            new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
                $: 'jquery',
                jQuery: 'jquery',
                'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
                lity: 'lity',
                imagesLoaded: 'imagesLoaded'
            })
        ]
    };
});
```

**package.json**

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
        "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
        "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --disable-host-check --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@tailwindcss/ui": "^0.6.0",
        "alpinejs": "^2.7.3",
        "axios": "^0.21.1",
        "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
        "laravel-mix": "^5.0.1",
        "lodash": "^4.17.19",
        "postcss-import": "^12.0.1",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^3.1.0",
        "tailwindcss": "^1.8.0",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.12",
        "jquery": "3.4.1",
        "lity": "^2.4.1",
        "imagesloaded": "^4.1.4"
    }
}
```

**main.js**

```
(function() {
      /* Setup Isotope */
      var grid = $('.portfolio-section .portfolio-grid');
      var filters = $('.portfolio-section .filter-control li');
      grid.imagesLoaded(function() {
        grid.isotope({
          itemSelector: '.portfolio-section .single-item',
          masonry: {
            horizontalOrder: true
          }
        });
        filters.on('click', function() {
          filters.removeClass('tab-active');
          $(this).addClass('tab-active');
          var selector = $(this).data('filter');
          grid.isotope({
            filter: selector,
            transitionDuration: '.25s'
          });
        });
      });
    }());
```

Answer (score 0):

I added the following codes to the beginning of the main.js file and the error was resolved

```
var imagesLoaded = require('imagesloaded');
var Isotope = require('isotope-layout');
var jQueryBridget = require('jquery-bridget');
imagesLoaded.makeJQueryPlugin( $ );
jQueryBridget( 'isotope', Isotope, $ );
```

Here is the final version

**webpack.mix.js**

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .postCss('resources/css/app.css', 'public/css', [
        require('postcss-import'),
        require('tailwindcss'),
    ])
    .webpackConfig(require('./webpack.config'));

/* Custom Mix Assets */

mix.styles([
    'public/guest/css/bootstrap-custom.css',
    'public/guest/css/ionicons.min.css',
    'public/guest/css/tiny-slider.css',
    'public/guest/css/lity.min.css',
    'public/guest/css/simplebar.min.css',
    'public/guest/css/jquery.mb.YTPlayer.min.css',
    'public/guest/css/main.css',
    'public/guest/css/colors/main-darkblue.css',
    'public/guest/css/custom.css',
], 'public/css/bundle.css').sourceMaps().version();

mix.js([
    //'public/guest/js/jquery.min.js',
    //'public/guest/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js',
    //'public/guest/js/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js',
    //'public/guest/js/isotope.pkgd.min.js',
    'public/guest/js/animatedModal.js',
    //'public/guest/js/tiny-slider.js',
    //'public/guest/js/lity.min.js',
    //'public/guest/js/simplebar.min.js',
    //'public/guest/js/jquery.mb.YTPlayer.min.js',
    'public/guest/js/main.js',
    'public/guest/js/custom.js',
], 'public/js/bundle.js').version();

mix.webpackConfig(webpack => {
    return {
        plugins: [
            new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
                $: 'jquery',
                jQuery: 'jquery',
                'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
                lity: 'lity',
                imagesLoaded: 'imagesLoaded'
            })
        ]
    };
});
```

**package.json**

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
        "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
        "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --disable-host-check --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@tailwindcss/ui": "^0.6.0",
        "alpinejs": "^2.7.3",
        "axios": "^0.21.1",
        "bootstrap": "4.3.1",
        "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
        "imagesloaded": "^4.1.4",
        "isotope-layout": "^3.0.6",
        "jquery": "^3.6.0",
        "jquery.mb.ytplayer": "^3.3.8",
        "laravel-mix": "^5.0.1",
        "lity": "2.4.0",
        "lodash": "^4.17.19",
        "postcss-import": "^12.0.1",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^3.1.0",
        "simplebar": "4.2.3",
        "tailwindcss": "^1.8.0",
        "tiny-slider": "^2.9.3",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.12",
        "jquery-bridget": "^3.0.0"
    }
}
```